# How do I use a single form in a view for a multiple-models in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a single form.

That form is currently in the View for the model Message.

Sometimes, I want to be able to associate a Contact (first name, last name) with that particular Message.  Contact is its own Model.

When the form is submitted, Message has a contact_id attribute.  I would want that contact_id to be associated, but also to create a new Contact.

How do I do that in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want both Contact and Message objects created from the same form and make them associated. As I told you in a previous question. form_for can take both stand alone values and even other objects values.

_form.html.erb

```
<% form_for :message do |f| %>
  <%= f.test_field :some_field %>
  ..
  ..
  <%= text_field :contact, :first_name %>
  <%= text_field :contact, :last_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
  @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
  @contact.message = @message
  if @contact.save # saves both contact and message if has_one relation is given in models
    ..
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

But this being said, it is better to use Nested form model. For that, you will have to write code centered on `contact`.

contacts_controller.rb

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
  @contact.message.build
end

def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
  if @contact.save
    ..
  else
    ..
  end
end
```

_form.html

```
<% form_for :contact do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :message do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_field :some_field %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :second_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

For this, you will have to specify `accepts_nested_attributes_for :message` in Contact.rb

Comment: thanks...I wasn't sure whether to nest them since, for example, a contact associated with one message may then be given to someone else in another message...BUT your point if I create the has_one (I assume I would have to pass the message_id attribute to contact_id) I only needed to save @contact is what I'm looking forward ... does that sound right?

Comment: yeah..if you have `has_one :message` in your contact.rb, then when you give `@contact.message = @message` and you save `@contact.save`, the contact object and the message object are saved to the database, along with saving `contact_id` in the message as `id` of the newly saved `contact` record. So, you need to do only `@contact.save`

Answer (score 0):

With a Nested Model Form.

Give a look at:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

It's based on Rails 2, but there isn't much to be done in order to make the code compatible with Rails 3.